# Build a class object from a string containing class properties and their value

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Suppose I have a class Employee :

```
Public class Employee
{
  public String ID {get;set;}
  public String Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Now i have stored some objects of this class in a text file or file with some other extension like .abc using StreamWriter as

```
<Employees>
 <Employee ID="1" Name="ABC" Age="30"/>
 <Employee ID="2" Name="XYZ" Age="35"/>
 <Employee ID="3" Name="PQR" Age="45"/>
</Employees>
```

Problem I m facing over here is that on reading this file using StreamReader i get a string and I m not able to extract the class objects from this string.

Can anyone please tell me how can I build an object of Employee class from the string I have obtained such that I can get a list of all the Employee objects that are stored in this string.

Comment: Take a look at (de-)serialization [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms233843.aspx) or [XDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Comment: Text file seems a valid XML file.

Comment: Lets say my file is of some other type like .abc extension.. Then in this case I read the contents of that file and get a string, then how can i derive the objects from that string..??

Comment: The file extension does not matter. It depends on how you create that file in the first place. Like Stephan Bauer or I stated the correct way to do that is using serialization and deserialization which transforms an object or a list of objects into some format that can be stored in a file (e.g. XML but can be JSON or anything - but to keep it simple: stored as XML) - this is called "serialization". Then you need to do the way back - "de-serialization". You can use whatever file ending you like ".xml" is a good thing for XML of course. 

If you wrote that XML by hand you have to do more work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use serialization - to create the XML:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
using(TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
   var e1 = new Employee();
   serializer.Serialize(writer, po);
}
```

To read the XML back into objects:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
var po = (Employee) serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

This is the code to read and write a single employee. To read or write multiple you can read more e.g. here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90c86ass%28VS.85%29.aspx)